# Error running ruby file

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Somewhere along the way my ruby environment has become bugged. I'm getting the following error message when I run the following command on OSX:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_static
  Referenced from: /Users/jaap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_static
  Referenced from: /Users/jaap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

The code I'm running is

```
./lib/ignite.rb crawl -p theage
```

on this app http://github.com/deadlysyntax/outrider

I've run *rvm implode* and totally reinstalled rvm and the gems, and still receive the same issue.

I get the feeling some part of the operation is calling a different ruby version than rvm, because if I switch my app to use ruby 2.1.1 the error message changes to a load error with the stack tracing calls to both rvm ruby 2.1.1 and system ruby 2.0.0

I don't know if they're related some way, and I thought cleaning out my rvm install and starting again would help.

Comment: What does `which ruby` show?

Comment: which ruby /Users/jaap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby

Comment: ruby -v ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]